# making a box-shadow stay above a ul element on hover

Tags: html, css

In this project of mine I'm just perfecting the navbar, as you can see the ordering menu item has some test drop down menus, I have the hover and active class of a blue box-shadow, but this box-shadow doesn't render over the new menu list, even with z-index's of 9999 for the first li and then 999 for the second, it still renders over the box shadow.

Here's the js fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybarpz3x/25/

thank you! This is all my nav css

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 999; }
  nav ul {
    float: right;
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #337ab7;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999; }
    nav ul .current-top-menu-item {
      box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #36B8C8; }
      nav ul .current-top-menu-item a {
        color: #204E76; }
    nav ul .top-menu-collapsed {
      padding: 20px 19px; }
    nav ul * {
      -webkit-transition: all 170ms ease-out;
      -moz-transition: all 170ms ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 170ms ease-out;
      transition: all 170ms ease-out; }
    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      font-weight: 600;
      position: relative;
      padding: 30px 24px;
      z-index: 9999; }
      nav ul li a {
        position: static; }
        nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active, nav ul li a:focus, nav ul li a:visited {
          text-decoration: none; }
      nav ul li div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 666666;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin: 22px 24px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
      nav ul li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 999; }
        nav ul li ul li {
          z-index: 999;
          text-align: center;
          float: none;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 8px 0px;
          display: block; }
      nav ul li:hover, nav ul li:active {
        z-index: 9999;
        cursor: hand;
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #36B8C8; }
        nav ul li:hover a, nav ul li:active a {
          color: #204E76; }
        nav ul li:hover ul, nav ul li:active ul {
          display: block; }
      nav ul li.active:after {
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #36B8C8; }
        nav ul li.active:after a {
          color: #204E76; }
  nav div a {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 70px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 3.8rem;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    color: #337ab7;
    float: left; }
    nav div a:hover, nav div a :active, nav div a :focus {
      color: #204E76;
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: hand; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add margin-top to your nav ul li ul style like this

```
nav ul li ul {

        margin-top: 4px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sj9kkrq4/

Answer (score 0):

TO **nav ul li ul** Give `margin-top:4px` here is the JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ybarpz3x/27/